# How to mock a webservice with XML response

Tags: web-services, mocking

I have a requirement to mock webservice call.
Here instead of actual webservice call I want the request to go to dummy server and 
server should reply my response xml.

The idea is to have these response xml file from actual webservice call and then modify it according to my need for mocking.

Regards,
Akash Sharma

Comment: What exactly do you need? you want to send an actual response from a dummy/fake web service, or just want to pass a dummy XML for stub method calls?

Comment: Use SOAP UI to create a mock service. It is easy and you can change the reponse as well.

Answer (score 2):

This can be helpful to someone with the similar problem. There is a service for mocking html, xml and json reponses at http://www.json-gen.com
via rest. You just need to define your structure and it will provide you a link for get request.

Answer (score 1):

Just make an XML file. Place it somewhere on your webserver and request it.

If you want to change its contents, just do so and see changes on your client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
We have a web application and our end class calls webservice we already have stubs generated for webservice here i want that those stubs fetch data from my dummy xml.

Comment: Read it through file reading and expose to the service after making any required changes